# File Usage Limitation Reached for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have a wordpress site, and it has more that 30k posts.
Every post has own feature image, and each feature image has 10 responsive sizes.
[#10076 post has 13 thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxBxy.png)

So there are about 300k image files, and this reaches to the File Usage Limit(inode limit) of hosting service.
[File Usage Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gbts.png)

How can I reduce the number of thumbnails?
For example, when we use 2~3 thumbnails, we can store 120k~180k posts.
Well, are there any other hosting services which can store more than 300k files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is possible.  There are several plugins in the WP repository that will automatically push uploads to S3 or some other CDN (e.g. [WP Offload S3 Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/)).

But the biggest challenge you'll face is in migrating the huge collection of images you already have.  Anything you run from a web browser will almost certainly die trying.  [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) is the only real option for large-scale maintenance tasks.  Take a look at [S3-Uploads](https://github.com/humanmade/S3-Uploads).

Alternatively you could push files to S3 manually and dynamically rewrite media URLs in WordPress by hooking into [post_thumbnail_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/) or some such. You could build a cachable "does this exist?" check into your filter so it only rewrites image URLs that can actually be found at Amazon.

Comment: Thank for your answer, Josh.
Is there any way to reduce the number of thumbnails? For example, when we use 2~3 thumbnails, we can store 120k~180k posts. 
Well, are there any other hosting service providers which allow to store more than 300k files?

Comment: To reduce the number of thumbnails, you need to do two things:
1. Remove unused size definitions from your theme;
2. Run the WP-CLI command `wp media regenerate` to rebuild your images (this will delete unused sizes, and recreate the used ones.

When a site gets to a certain size, it is time to move from shared hosting to Dedicated Virtual hosting.  With a DV account, you're typically given a set percentage of a machine's resources to do with as you please.  [Linode](https://linode.com) is great. DVs require system admin knowledge to put together and keep safe, so a CDN might be better for you

Answer (score 0):

empty your trash folder in File Manager and file usage will drop significantly.